# How to get DIV attributes with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I get the `href` of `a` elements by

```
const hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => 
Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('a'), ({ href }) => href));
```

but when I try to get `aria-label` or `data-xx` of `div` elements, this method does not work.

Why is that and how can I get `aria-label` or `data-xx` attributes of `div` elements?

**HTML**

```
<div class="test" arial-label="something" data-all="something">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem: DOM node attribute ≠ HTML element attribute

Only some of the HTML attributes are exposed on the DOM node. And even the exposed one might contain a different value: The `href` attribute of the DOM node is not the same as the attribute written into the HTML (`<a href="..."></a>`). To give an example:

```js
<a id="link" href="test.html">Link</a>
```

Accessing `document.querySelector('#link').href` will return the full path (e.g. `http://example.com/test.html`) instead of `test.html`. To get the original element attribute you have to use the function [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

### Solution

Coming back to your code, that means you can read `aria-label` and `data-all` by using `getAttribute` like this:

```js
Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('div'), (el) => el.getAttribute('aria-label'));
```

```js
Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('div'), (el) => el.getAttribute('data-all'));
```

---

For accessing the `data` attribute, there is an additional solution available. You can access the `data` values by using a special attribute called [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), which allows to read the value of  `data-xx` like this:

```js
Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('div'), (el) => el.dataset.xx);
```